# How to find the index of a dropped item in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

How can I find the index of a item dropped into a list in flex using a spark list?

Answer (score 1):

`LayoutBase` has a method `calculateDropLocation` that takes a `DragEvent` and returns a `DropLocation`.

In the handler for `DragEvent.DRAG_DROP` on your list you do something like this:

```
var dl:DropLocation = myList.layout.calculateDropLocation(myDragEvent);
var dropIndex:int = dl.dropIndex;
```

The relevant links:

[calculateDropLocation()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/layouts/supportClasses/LayoutBase.html#calculateDropLocation%28%29)

[DropLocation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/layouts/supportClasses/DropLocation.html)

[DragEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/events/DragEvent.html)

Answer (score 0):

In a [dragComplete](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#event%3adragComplete) event listener, you can do something like this:

```
var indexOfDroppedItem : int = list.dataProvider.getItemIndex(event.dragSource );
```

Answer (score 0):

Hiii I am Anil Mhetre,
Here is the solution for finding the dropping index of S:data grid
Solution:-
Add an event listener to data grid on which we want to find dropping index
e.g

```
id_DG_TestCond.addEventListener(GridEvent.GRID_MOUSE_UP,
getgridselectedIndex);
here id_DG_TestCond is the id of datagrid & getgridselectedIndex is the event handler for GridEvent.GRID_MOUSE_UP.Event handler, for the same given below:
protected function getgridselectedIndex(event:GridEvent):void
            {
             var droppingIndex = event.currentTarget.grid.hoverRowIndex;
            }
```